# What's the speed of an Internet connection in Ubuntu?

Tags: broadband

Does Internet access work faster in Ubuntu compared to Windows 7/8/8.1? Is the peer speed also the same compared to what we get on Windows?

Answer (score 4):

Network stack optimisation differences between Windows or Ubuntu will pale into insignificance compared to driver issues. *Some* Linux drivers (especially in the wireless world) are unreliable but so are *some* Windows versions. There isn't one rule for every bit of hardware.

I can anecdotally say that I'm very happy with wired networking and I'm occasionally angry with wireless networking but generally speaking, it's always been fast enough for purpose.

But it's impossible to give you a solid answer other than: **test it and find out**. Ubuntu is free and you can run a network test directly from a LiveCD. Then you'll know *exactly* how they compare.